# Mapbox GL JS relations

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have three layers as follows;

1. ski areas (polygons)
2. ski lifts (ways)
3. ski rund (ways)

There is a unique ID that makes it relate back to the ski area.  This is an example:

1. ski areas (polygons) // id= 3cb98511ef6187cef677a3b8630430c57bb0e400
2. ski lifts (ways) // skiArea = { "properties": { "activities": [ "downhill" ], "generated": false, "id": "3cb98511ef6187cef677a3b8630430c57bb0e400",...
3. ski rund (ways): { "properties": { "activities": [ "downhill" ], "generated": false, "id": "3cb98511ef6187cef677a3b8630430c57bb0e400",

How are relations handled normally in mapbox gl js?  What I would like to do is something like this;

- When the ski area is clicked, it will give statistical info such as percent beginner, intermediate and expert, number and length of lifts, number and length of runs.
- when the lift or the run is clicked, I am able to give stats for the object

Just wondering how best to handle this.  Beginner here.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to your application, and not really a concern of Mapbox GL JS. You would need to write a "click handler", a function that does whatever calculation and state management is necessary to compute, update state, and then re-render parts of the application that need this bit of state to be correctly rendered.

I would recommend doing some tutorials with Mapbox GL JS that include Redux, to learn about actions, reducers, etc. [This is literally the first hit](https://medium.com/critigenopensource/an-approach-to-integrating-mapboxgl-in-react-redux-b50d82bc0ed0) when I do a search.

Comment: I was reading about recipes and in particular, Feature union with group_by.  This may work with "id=".  This is stated in the page:  "...so that if one of them is selected, they are all selected" here; https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/reference/#expressions-reference. I was originally thinking like what you have written which would be a big undertaking but would UNION work?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this into the function you created the layer with.

```
map.on('click', 'PolygonLayerId', function (e) {
            new mapboxgl.Popup()
                    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                    .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.your layer attributes 1 + " : " + e.features[0].properties.your layer attributes 2)
                    .addTo(map);
        });
```

Comment: There are hundreds of ski areas in one layer and even more ski lift and runs in 2 more layers (total 3 layers).  The objects in each layer (eg ski area to ski lift and ski run) are tied together with "id": ###...  I dont think the above code accounts for this.  Thanks though.